# how can I merge 1 commit from a branch to another branch

Tags: git

I switch to a branch (branch1) in git and I did multiple commits there in that branch.
And now I switch to another branch (branch2), how can I merge 1 (the latest in branch1) to this new branch (branch2)?

If I do 'git merge branch1' when I am in branch2, i will merge all commits I did in branch1. I do not want that i only want the latest one.

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want:

```
$ git cherry-pick COMMITID
```

See the [**`git cherry_pick`** man page](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-cherry-pick.html):

> Given one or more existing commits, apply the change each one introduces, recording a new commit for each.
>   This requires your working tree to be clean (no modifications from the `HEAD` commit).

Comment: I took the liberty to put your link as text and add a small excerpt. Feel free to edit or revert if you find this modification not appropriate.